# Como resolver o CSS do submit do Struts?

Tags: css, struts2

Observe a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já fiz de tudo para colocar esse botão no lugar certo que não consigo, ele só fica estranhamente no canto da tela, é um comportamento muito estranha para o um botão.

Essas foram minhas tentativas

```
.button_struts{
position: relative;
right: -780px;
top: -69px;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essas configurações de CSS funcionou para corrigir o problema, porém não é uma boa prática porque não fica responsivo, eu coloquei esse botão na força, não está certo;

Alguém poderia me dar uma sugestão?

Esse é meu HTML;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddObservacao" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <s:form cssClass="form-horizontal" role="form" id="formObservacao" action="NaoConformidade!addObservacao" method="post">
        <s:hidden id="codigoNaoConformidade" name="observacao.id" value="%{observacao.id}" />
        <s:hidden name="idRegistroSelecionado" id="idRegistroSelecionado" value=""/>
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="fecharModalObservacao();" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Observação</h4>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <input
                        id="idObservacao"
                        type="text" 
                        class="form-control"
                        name="observacao" 
                        value="" />

                    <div id="msgObservacao" ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" align="right">
                    <s:submit onclick="adicionarObservacao(event);" cssClass="btn btn-primary button_struts" key="Salvar"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </s:form>
</div>
```

Informações adicionais

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também tentei dessa forma;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddObservacao" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <s:form cssClass="form-horizontal" role="form" id="formObservacao" action="NaoConformidade!addObservacao" method="post">
        <s:hidden id="codigoNaoConformidade" name="observacao.id" value="%{observacao.id}" />
        <s:hidden name="idRegistroSelecionado" id="idRegistroSelecionado" value=""/>
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>

                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Observação</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <input
                            id="idObservacao"
                            type="text" 
                            class="form-control"
                            name="observacao" 
                            value="" />


                        <div id="msgObservacao" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" align="right">
                        <s:submit onclick="adicionarObservacao(event);" cssClass="btn btn-primary" key="Salvar"/>
                    </div>

           </div>
        </div>
    </s:form>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc quer colocar no canto direito do footer da modal?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo!   :)

Comment: Mas os botões do footer da modal já ficam à direita por padrão. Não precisa alterar o CSS.

Comment: Ele não está ficando a direita, ele está ficando como está na imagem.

Comment: Está ficando como na imagem pq vc está aplicando propriedades que deslocam o botão. Esse modal é Bootstrap, certo? Tenta sem essas propriedades, ou seja, apague esse CSS `.button_struts{
position: relative;
right: -780px;
top: -69px;
}`

Comment: Eu sou difícil de explica, o fato de você não ter entendido não é culpa sua, o problema é o seguinte, sem essas configurações de CSS que coloquei a tela fica como está na primeira imagem dessa postagem, mas se eu colocar essas configurações de CSS vai ficar corrigiso porém não é uma boa prática porque eu coloquei o botão no lugar a força, eu preciso colocar o botão no lugar de maneira correta.

Comment: Qual a versão do Bootstrap que vc tá usando?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.6

Answer (score 1):

O footer da modal do Bootstrap 3 já alinha os elementos à direita por padrão, devido à propriedade nativa `text-align: right`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, você não precisa aplicar estilos para posicionar o botão, ela já fica na posição correta normalmente, conforme mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddObservacao">
  Abrir modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddObservacao" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="formObservacao" action="NaoConformidade!addObservacao" method="post">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="fecharModalObservacao();" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Observação</h4>
               </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <input
                        id="idObservacao"
                        type="text" 
                        class="form-control"
                        name="observacao" 
                        value="" />

                    <div id="msgObservacao" ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button onclick="adicionarObservacao(event);" class="btn btn-primary button_struts" key="Salvar">Salvar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

> Também não precisa desse atributo `align="right"` na div footer da
>   modal. E faltou fechar a div do header da modal, caso contrário ela vai "engolir" a div do footer.

Comment: Eu entendo que está se esforçando para me ajudar, o botão ficar realmente no lugar certo, porém não consigo submeter as informações inseridas em tela no banco de dados, a tela só consegue salva no banco de dados as informações inseridas na tela se for usar o componente s:submit do struts, é por isso que estou tentando fazer esse componente funcionar e não usar um componente do bootstrap.

Comment: Já percebeu que falta fechar a div `<div class="modal-header">`?

Comment: Vai no inspecionar elementos do navegador e veja como é renderizado esse código: `<s:submit onclick="adicionarObservacao(event);" cssClass="btn btn-primary button_struts" key="Salvar"/>`.

Comment: Ele esta fechando normal, eu criei um arquivo gif e coloquei na postagem, dar uma olhada para mim por favor, você vai ver que está fechando corretamente as divs

Comment: Tá fechando não. Seu gif mostra que a div do footer está dentro da div do header.

Comment: Eu desci vários níveis de div para baixo para ver se ele ficava no lugar, mas não adiantou, a forma como poderia me ajuda seria colocar da forma que você acha que deve fica.

Comment: Tem que fechar a div do header. Coloca uma `</div>` antes de `<div class="modal-body">`.

Comment: acabei de realizar essa tentativa, e não funcionou, eu coloquei essa tentativa na postagem.